# Problema con el scroll en angular version chat

Tags: javascript, angular

se que es una pregunta recurrente pero he buscado y no logro encontrar alguien con el mismo problema.
Estoy desarrollando en angular un componente de un chat y como más de un compañero ha preguntado quiero que al iniciarse el componente se vaya hacia abajo. Basándome en esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232731/angular-2-scroll-to-bottom-chat-style lo he implementeado pero casi siempre se queda un poco por encima de donde debería acabar: [image: imagen del chat]

He estado imprimiendo las variables y siguiendo este código:

```
scrollToBottom(): void {
console.log("ScrollToBottom")
try {
console.log(this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop)
console.log(this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
console.log("DONE")
console.log(this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop)
console.log(this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
} catch (err) { console.log(err) }
}
```

se imprimen los siguientes logs:

0
1539
DONE
1139
1539

por lo que supongo que algo en la asignación se debe de estar haciendo mal pero no encuentro qué.

Las versiones que tengo son:
Angular CLI: 10.1.4
Node: 14.8.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 10.1.4

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias.

Comment: Elimina la etiqueta de AngularJS y cambia el título, ya que es otra tecnología. A partir de Angular 2.0 ya no se llama AngularJS, se llama simplemente Angular. Saludos

Comment: Necesito saber cuando llamas a la función scrollToBottom()

Comment: a la funcion scrollToBottom() la llamo cuando inicio, en el onInit() y cuando el usuario envía un mensaje nuevo.